# How to Make a String Move to the Right (Video Services in Assembly)

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, tasm

Good day! I'm new in assembly language (TASM in particular) and what I have here is a simple ball (string, made up of characters) and I want to move it to the right.

```
  .MODEL  SMALL
  .STACK  100
  .DATA

    ball DB 10," #######"
         DB 10,"#       #"
         DB 10,"#       #"
         DB 10,"#       #"
         DB 10," #######","$"
    ROW1 DB 5   
    ROW2 DB 10
    COL DB 25       
    MAX     DB ?
    RAND    DB ?
    ATT DB 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5

 .CODE
    .STARTUP
        mov ax, @data       ;required
        mov ds, ax

        MOV AX, 3       ; 80x25 color
        INT 10H         ; video BIOS call   
        MOV AH, 2       ; set cursor position
        MOV BH, 0       ; display page number
        MOV DH, ROW1        ; row number
        MOV DL, COL     ; column number
        INT 10H         ; video BIOS call
        LEA BP, ATT ; point to first attribute array
        CALL FAR PTR MOVE  ; display first line of video text

        MOV MAX, AL ;max=10
            @TIMELOOPS1:
                ;get system time
                MOV AH, 2Ch
                INT 21h
                MOV RAND, DH
            @WAIT1SEC1:
                MOV AH, 2Ch
                INT 21h
                CMP RAND, DH
                JE @WAIT1SEC1

                MOV AH, 2
                MOV DL, '.'
                INT 21H
                MOV AH, 2       ; set cursor position
                MOV BH, 0       ; display page number
                MOV DH, ROW2        ; row number
                MOV DL, COL     ; column number
                INT 10H         ; video BIOS call
                LEA BP, ATT     ; point to first attribute array
                CALL FAR PTR MOVE   ; display first line of video text

                ;clear

                DEC MAX
                CMP MAX, 0
                JNE @TIMELOOPS1     
    .EXIT

    MOVE PROC FAR
        MOV SI, 0   ; set up array pointer
        NEXT:   
            MOV AL, ball[SI]; get name character
            ;xor al, al
            CMP AL, '$'   ; exit if character is 0
            JZ EXIT  
            CMP AL, 10
            JE LF
            MOV BH, 0   ; display page number
            MOV BL, [BP+SI] ; get attribute
            MOV CX, 1   ; do 1 character
            MOV AH, 9   ; write character/attribute on screen
            INT 10H     ; video BIOS call
            INC SI      ; point to next character/attribute
            ADD DL, 1   ; move one column to the right
            MOV AH, 2   ; set cursor position
            INT 10H     ; video BIOS call
            JMP NEXT    ; and continue

        EXIT:  ret

        LF:
            MOV BH, 0   ; display page number
            MOV BL, [BP+SI] ; get attribute
            MOV CX, 1   ; do 1 character
            MOV AH, 0Ah   ; write character/attribute on screen
            MOV AL, 10
            INT 12H     ; video BIOS call
            INC SI      ; point to next character/attribute
            ADD DH, 1   ; move one column to the right
            MOV DL,0
            MOV AH, 2   ; set cursor position
            INT 10H     ; video BIOS call
            JMP NEXT    ; and continue

    MOVE ENDP

END
```

What I'm trying to do is print a dot `.` every one second so the ball will be moved to the right. But it just prints a dot then prints the ball string once again. 
 
Right now, I'm thinking to clear the initial ball then move it to the next 3 columns. However, it will be confusing because it already manipulates the column and row per character in order to print the whole string.
Please help me to make the ball move. Thank you very much!

**EDIT** 
Following Sir Jim Mischel, I added `MOV AL, COL`, `INC AL`, `MOV COL, AL` right after calling `MOVE`. However, it only displays the ball once and the program doesn't stop (I can't see `J:/TASM/BIN`).

```
  .MODEL  SMALL
  .STACK  100
  .DATA

    ball DB 10," #######"
         DB 10,"#       #"
         DB 10,"#       #"
         DB 10,"#       #"
         DB 10," #######","$"
    ROW1 DB 5   
    ROW2 DB 10
    COL DB 25       
    MAX     DB ?
    RAND    DB ?
    ATT DB 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5

 .CODE
    .STARTUP
        mov ax, @data       ;required
        mov ds, ax

        MOV MAX, AL ;max=10
            @TIMELOOPS1:
                ;get system time
                MOV AH, 2Ch
                INT 21h
                MOV RAND, DH
            @WAIT1SEC1:
                MOV AH, 1
                INT 16h
                ;JNZ @ENDPROGRAM
                MOV AH, 2Ch
                INT 21h
                CMP RAND, DH
                JE @WAIT1SEC1

                MOV AX, 3       ; 80x25 color
                INT 10H         ; video BIOS call   
                MOV AH, 2       ; set cursor position
                MOV BH, 0       ; display page number
                MOV DH, ROW2        ; row number
                MOV DL, COL     ; column number
                INT 10H         ; video BIOS call
                LEA BP, ATT     ; point to first attribute array
                CALL FAR PTR MOVE   ; display first line of video text
                MOV AL, COL
INC AL
MOV COL, AL

                ;clear

                DEC MAX
                CMP MAX, 0
                JNE @TIMELOOPS1     
    .EXIT

    MOVE PROC FAR
        MOV SI, 0   ; set up array pointer
        NEXT:   
            MOV AL, ball[SI]; get name character
            ;xor al, al
            CMP AL, '$'   ; exit if character is 0
            JZ EXIT  
            CMP AL, 10
            JE LF
            MOV BH, 0   ; display page number
            MOV BL, [BP+SI] ; get attribute
            MOV CX, 1   ; do 1 character
            MOV AH, 9   ; write character/attribute on screen
            INT 10H     ; video BIOS call
            INC SI      ; point to next character/attribute
            ADD DL, 1   ; move one column to the right
            MOV AH, 2   ; set cursor position
            INT 10H     ; video BIOS call
            JMP NEXT    ; and continue

        EXIT:  ret

        LF:
            MOV BH, 0   ; display page number
            MOV BL, [BP+SI] ; get attribute
            MOV CX, 1   ; do 1 character
            MOV AH, 0Ah   ; write character/attribute on screen
            MOV AL, 10
            INT 12H     ; video BIOS call
            INC SI      ; point to next character/attribute
            ADD DH, 1   ; move one column to the right
            MOV DL,0
            MOV AH, 2   ; set cursor position
            INT 10H     ; video BIOS call
            JMP NEXT    ; and continue

    MOVE ENDP

END
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have the following just before you call the `MOVE` proc:

```
MOV DL, COL     ; column number
INT 10H         ; video BIOS call
LEA BP, ATT     ; point to first attribute array
CALL FAR PTR MOVE   ; display first line of video text
```

If you want to move right each time through the loop, you have to increment the `COL` value each time through the loop. I would suggest adding the following after the call to `MOVE`:

```
MOV AL, COL
INC AL
MOV COL, AL
```

So the first time through the loop, `COL` is 25. Next time it's 26, etc . . .

Comment: Thank you! However, it does not move. (Please see edit). Maybe I need to clear the previous ball first? If so, how can I do that? I tried `MOV AX, 600h`,  `MOV BH, 7`, `XOR CX, CX`, `MOV DX, 184Fh`, `INT 10h` but it clears the whole screen.

Comment: The easiest way to clear the ball would be to call your `MOVE` proc again, but use an array of spaces rather than the ball characters. You'll have to modify `MOVE` so you can pass the starting address (i.e. the ball or the spaces) in a register pair. Or, there might be a BIOS call to clear some number of columns starting at a given cursor position; I don't recall. It's been a long time since I did any work with the BIOS.